# Display value and actual value in excel

Tags: excel

I have created a cell collection, let's say in cells `J3:J6` having the values: `A, B, C, D.` In cell `A1`, I validate the inserted values and one can insert only the values in the collection.
Now, the inserted value lets say `A` corresponds to the value `1` for my calculations.

Is there a way to display value (`A`) and actual value (`1`) in one cell?
Is there any easy way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short, no**. That being said you can easily use some IF statments and other ways to treat the letter A as a value of 1 in your calculation, depending on how you do it.

**UPDATE**:
Here is a nice way to in VBA to treat letters as numbers (A = 1, B = 2) when you do your process.

```
variable = Asc(Range("A1")) - 64
```

As you probobly know, capital A is 65 and it goes up, so you can get the number easily this way (A=1, B=2 etc.)

Comment: Though if my collection becomes larger it is an issue ... Thanks though for sharing your knowledge...

Comment: You could store a 'legend' in an veryHidden sheet that you could reference to get the value that corresponds with the letter/item in your list.

Comment: Updated my answer with an even easier way of doing this if you are working with ABCDE...